# LuaJ Iterate over Object Array in Coerced Java Object

Tags: java, lua, luaj

I'm working with LuaJ 3.0.1 and am having issues iterating over an array contained in a coerced Java object in my Lua script. Currently, here's what I'm doing:

I have a Java class that contains an array of objects. Something like

```
public class Foo {

   public Bar[] bars;

}
```

I have a [LuaFunction](http://luaj.org/luaj/3.0/api/org/luaj/vm2/LuaFunction.html) that takes Foo as one of its arguments. I call this function, passing an instance of Foo as follows:

```
luaFunction.invoke(new LuaValue[]{
   CoerceJavaToLua.coerce(fooInstance)
});
```

However, the problem arises in the Lua script itself, where I need to iterate over the Bar array. I tried using the following code, but this produces an org.luaj.vm2.LuaError with the message "bad argument: table expected, got userdata" on the line containing the `ipairs` function.

```
for i,bar in ipairs(fooInstance.bars) do
   ... do stuff with each bar ...
end
```

It seems that the Bar array does not become a table when the Foo object is coerced to Lua, instead becoming a `userdata` type. Thus, it cannot be passed to the `ipairs` function.

Is there any way I can make it so that the `Bar` array is treated as a table in Lua? Alternatively, are there any options aside from `ipairs` that would be more appropriate for looping through the array?

Comment: `local i=0; while fooInstance.bars[i+1] do i=i+1; local bar = fooInstance.bars[i]; ... end`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff thanks! That worked perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, from Egor's comment on my original question, was to use the following code:

```
local i = 0
while fooInstance.bars[i+1] do

   i = i + 1
   local bar = fooInstance.bars[i]

   ... do stuff with bar ...

end
```